# Textarea 100% height in IE

Tags: css, textarea, height

How do I get my `<textarea>` to have a height of 100% and work in IE7/6? `height:100%` works fine in all other browsers but IE just doesn't want to accept anything other than specific values. Javascript is a possible solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for an element to achieve 100% height in IE6, you will need to specify a fixed height of its parent element. If you want to make the element the full-length of your page, apply height:100%; to both the html and body elements.

```
/*100% height of the parent element for IE6*/ 
#parent {height:500px;}
#child {height:100%;}

/*100% of the page length for IE6*/ 
html, body {height:100%;}
#fullLength {height:100%;}
```

Taken from: [http://www.virtuosimedia.com/](http://www.virtuosimedia.com/tutorials/ultimate-ie6-cheatsheet-how-to-fix-25-internet-explorer-6-bugs#one-hundred-percent-height)

I'm guessing the same applies for IE7.

Comment: This applies to divs though, not textarea. I have tried that.

Comment: Can't you wrap the `<label>` that's associated with the `<textarea>` around it and apply the parent styles to it?

Answer (score 3):

I want to leave an answer here, beacause I have the same problem and answer above is not fully  helpfull.

For all browsers except IE6-7

```
  div#parent {height:500px;}
  textarea#child {height:100%;}
```

But for IE6-7 you need to set:

```
  textarea#child {
      height:100%;
      position: absolute;
  }
```

Comment: oh. thanks a little mistake. must be div#parent and textarea#child

Comment: @Teneff, `textarea#child` means a textarea whose id is `child`. If you want to select the element whose id is `child` *inside* the textarea, then you should use `textarea #child`. Notice there is a space between `textarea` and `#child`.