# CSS height=100% for Textarea isn't working in IE6/IE7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EFEFEF;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, fieldset, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #content{
            height:200px;
        }
        fieldset,textarea{
            border: 0 none;
        }
        #LeftPanel
        {
            width: 48%;
            float: left;
            height:100%;
        }
        .window {
            border: 1px solid #ADADAD;
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
        }
        .top {
            height: 25%;
        }
        .bottom {
            height: 75%;
        }
        .code{
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <fieldset id="LeftPanel">
        <div id="div_A" class="window top">
            <textarea id="code_A" class="code">A</textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="div_B" class="window bottom">
            <textarea id="code_B" class="code">B</textarea>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It works well in Chrome, Firefox, IE8/IE9, but it doesn't work in IE6/IE7.

In IE6/IE7:

[image]

In Firefox:

[image]

Who can help me? Thanks!

Comment: FYI ie6 is way too old, may be obsolete, and user's using ie7 is also very minor so giving support for them is not a best idea.

Comment: You can refer this URL for IE style http://www.virtuosimedia.com/dev/css/ultimate-ie6-cheatsheet-how-to-fix-25-internet-explorer-6-bugs#one-hundred-percent-height

Comment: but in china,a large amount of users use ie6

Comment: China and South Korea have the world's biggest user bases for IE6. In China the reason is software piracy (OS with included browser), in SK it's legacy software for identifying yourself on the internet. Wake up @HarryJoy, it's not cool to ignore your target audience. If your audience uses IE6, you'd better code for IE6.

Comment: @nikc.org: OOPS!! seems like I should search the net before commenting. ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it ,when i add cols and rows property to Textarea,it work fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
         body {
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EFEFEF;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, fieldset, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #content{
            height:200px;
        }
        fieldset,textarea{
            border: 0 none;
        }
        #LeftPanel
        {
            width: 48%;
            float: left;
            height:100%;
        }
        .window {
            border: 1px solid #ADADAD;
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
        }
        .top {
            height: 25%;
        }
        .bottom {
            height: 75%;
        }
        .code{
            width:100%; 
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <fieldset id="LeftPanel">
        <div id="div_A" class="window top">
            <textarea rows="20" cols="40" id="code_A" class="code">A</textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="div_B" class="window bottom">
            <textarea rows="20" cols="4" id="code_B" class="code">B</textarea>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the containing element's height to 100%.  IE6/7 sets the height based on the parent's height.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution works in IE7/8, but not IE6 (I just put CSS here).

Actually, for IE6, the you cannot use "height:100%". The bug can be found here:
[Textarea 100% height in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036109/textarea-100-height-in-ie)

```
    body {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EFEFEF;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, fieldset, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #content{
        height:200px;
        position:relative;
    }
    fieldset,textarea{
        border: 0 none;
    }
    #LeftPanel
    {
        width: 48%;
        float: left;
        height:100%;
        position:relative;
    }
    .window {
        position:relative;
        border: 1px solid #ADADAD;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
    }
    .top {
        height: 25%;
    }
    .bottom {
        height: 75%;
    }
    .code{
        width:100%; 
        height: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: thanks your answer,but it don't work
I found it ,when i add cols and rows property to Textarea,it work fine

Comment: The problem occur, because for any browser, it is necessary for child elements to find its parent to determine its size and location. So, adding "position:relative" to its parent will solve the problem. But for IE6, since textarea contains bugs, there could be no solution to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wasn't able to set `height:100%` for `textarea` within absolutely positioned `div` (`cols` and `rows` were set).

Thus, for IE7 I've stretched `textarea` with `position:absolute` (this way won't work in any normal browser, so I've used IE7 CSS `*` hack):

CSS:

```
.textarea-wrapper {
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 67px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: auto;

    *width: 99%;
    *position: absolute;
    *top: 0;
    *bottom: 0;
    *left: 0;
    *right: 0;
    *height: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="textarea-wrapper">
    <textarea id="new-comment" rows="2" cols="2"></textarea>
</div>
```